# Filter TOP thing GROUP by ID

Tags: mysql

I have a task to filter :
artist, song_count, most_popular_artist_song, most_acoustic_artist_song, most_energised_artist_song

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGEoQ.png)

How to do it? need use select in select?

My code now:

```
SELECT artists AS artist, count(name) AS songs, name , acousticness, energy , popularity
 FROM lt.artist
 GROUP BY artists 
 ORDER BY popularity DESC, acousticness DESC, energy DESC
```

[RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fG3bw.png)

But in acousticness and energy columns I need get that song name with most acousticness, energy and where this artist sing it, something like this:

```
    artist|song_count|most_popular_song|most_acoustic_song |most_energised_song
 
Justin Timberlake | 150 | Mirrors | Cry me a river | Can’t stop the feeling
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes for a surprisingly intricate query. Your requirement is to extract four different items for each artist from your table.

So, start with a subquery to get the metrics.

```
                 SELECT artists,
                        COUNT(*) song_count, 
                        MAX(energy) energy,
                        MAX(popularity) popularity,
                        MAX(acousticness) acousticness
                   FROM artist
                  GROUP BY artists
```

Then you must use JOIN operations to recover the names of the songs with those MAX values.

```
SELECT m.artists artist
       m.song_count,
       pop.name most_popular,
       aco.name most_acoustic,
       ene.name most_energized
  FROM (   /* the subquery from ^^^ */
                 SELECT artists,
                        COUNT(*) song_count, 
                        MAX(energy) energy,
                        MAX(popularity) popularity,
                        MAX(acousticness) acousticness
                   FROM artist
                  GROUP BY artists
       ) m
  JOIN artist pop 
          ON m.artists = pop.artists AND m.popularity = pop.popularity
  JOIN artist aco
          ON m.artists = aco.artists AND m.acousticness= aco.acousticness
  JOIN artist ene
         ON m.artists = ene.artists AND m.energy= ene.energy
 ORDER BY m.popularity DESC, m.acousticness DESC, m.energy DESC
```

SQL lacks a simple syntax for "retrieve the row with the highest value" in GROUP BY operations, unfortunately. So you have to do this kind of thing.

The good news? Query optimizers do well with this sort of thing given the right indexes.   A suitable index might be (no guarantees)

```
ALTER TABLE artist 
     ADD INDEX (artist, energy, popularity, acousticness);
```

Comment: I think this is good idea. But query running long time, because data from CSV file where rows about 100000 :? And where use DISTINCT because some actors have two same rows

Comment: If your query is too slow, please ask another question about that. Use the [tag:query-optimization] tag.

Comment: Okey, but where use DISTINCT in this query? Now result:
 are two or more same artist with same songs

Comment: It looks like you have two songs with precisely the same popularity rating. Your requirement did not say what to do in that situation. You should ask another question, and include both sample data and your desired result. I